# How to get one row out of many rows with same column id

Tags: sql-server, query, row

I have a use case in which I have three tables.

### Courses Table

```
Course_ Id   Name
 1   MathMatics
 2   Physics
```

### Teacher Table

```
 Teacher_ID  Teacher_Name
    1    AAA
    2    BBB
```

### TeacherVsCourses Table

```
 id  Course_id  Teacher_id 
 1   1   1
 2   2   1
 3   1   2
```

My application is programmed using the MVC design pattern of ASP.NET. I am saving individual records into the database table as shown below:

[image]

---

What I want in my view is instead of two rows for `Teacher-id=1`, I need 1 row with comma separated courses.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: This has nothing to do with partitioning - I have removed that tag and put in listagg (aka string_agg AFAIK in SQL Server - not an expert - could you please tag the question with your RDBMS to be sure). Just as a minor note - SQL was not designed for nor is it good at string manipulation - doing what you want requires breaching first normal form and it makes getting individual subjects by teacher back again difficult also. Perhaps you should ask yourself why you want to do this and maybe have a rethink? p.s. welcome to the forum! :-)

Comment: p.p.s. images are discouraged here for the reasons outlined in this [link](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/470530).

Comment: Could you give a written example of how the data would look? Please [edit] your question and add an example output. Please also add the version of your SQL Server Edition. Can be helpful.

Comment: How will you display the additional Course columns (Course_assignment_date etc), comma separated as well? Also, please include version information, as the solution can vary substantially if you're on an earlier version of SQL Server.

Answer (score -1):

You can return a comma separated list of values by using the string_agg function.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: Link only answers are frowned upon here - perhaps you could also provide an example or even use the construct to provide an actual answer to the OP's question?